# Youtrack Workflow to set issue due date based on issue start date + estimate

Tags: youtrack

I am trying to set up a workflow on youtrack where it sets automatically the end date based on the start date + estimates.

For example, my issue start date is 2022/10/01 and it has an estimate of 10d (10 days, for example). I want that the end date to be set of 2022/10/10.

I couldn't figure out how to set this rule as I couldn't user the workflow constructor for it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of a similar workflow that automatically adds the `Planned time` value to `Start date` field and writes the result in the `Due date` field:

```
const entities = require('@jetbrains/youtrack-scripting-api/entities');

exports.rule = entities.Issue.onChange({
  title: 'End date',
  guard: (ctx) => {
    return (ctx.issue.fields.isChanged(ctx.Plan) || ctx.issue.fields.isChanged(ctx.StartDate)) && ctx.issue.fields.Plan != null && ctx.issue.fields.StartDate != null;
  },
  action: (ctx) => {
    const issue = ctx.issue;
    var periodestimate = issue.fields.Plan;
    var minutesestimate = !periodestimate ? 0 : (periodestimate.getMinutes() + 60 * (periodestimate.getHours() + 24 * (periodestimate.getDays() + 7 * periodestimate.getWeeks())));
    ctx.issue.fields.EndDate = issue.fields.StartDate + (minutesestimate * 60000);
  },
  requirements: {
      Plan: {
      name: "Planned time",
      type: entities.Field.periodType
    },
    EndDate: {
      name: "Due Date",
      type: entities.Field.dateType
    },
    StartDate: {
    name: "Start Date",
    type: entities.Field.dateType
    }
  }
});
```